# Grid and Pager in UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am trying to build a grid which has pagination controls. I understand that `DataGrid` of GWT provides the Grid and `SimplePager` provides pagination.

I have taken the approach shown in the example http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

But this is just a composition where my wrapped component is neither a Grid not a Pager, but a composition of both.

If I want to extends the `DataGrid` of GWT to provide pagination how can I achieve that using `UiBinder`?

Please ask me any number of questions if something is not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want a Element that is a SimplePager and an DataGrid at the same time. What I don't understand is why you need something like this?
I just don't get what you need and a composition like http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#! doesn't have? If you need to be able to call the functions of a DataGrid, then I would suppose you make an Class that extends DataGrid.

```
public class MyDataGrid extends DataGrid<EngineJobDTO> {

    private static MyDataGridUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyDataGridUiBinder.class);


    interface MyDataGridUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyDataGrid> {
    }


    @UiField
    SimplePager pager;


    public MyDataGrid() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
        pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources, false, 0, true);
        pager.setDisplay(this);
    }
}
```

UiBinder for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
xmlns:c="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client">
<c:SimplePager ui:field='pager'  location='CENTER'/>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And then you have your own DataGrid with paging. I don't know If this really works, i've only done something similar with a normal grid.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: +1. You have understood my problem properly. I will try it out and let you know. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have a doubt. isn't it mandatory for `MyDataGrid` to extend from `Composite`????

Comment: AbstractHasData extends Composite -> AbstractCellTable extends AbstractHasData -> DataGrid extends AbstractCellTable -> MyDataGrid extends DataGrid so it also Extends Composite.

Answer (score 0):

The sample uses a `DataGrid` and `SimplePager` attached to a `UiBinder` structure. Both are widgets and are unrelated from each other, so you can attach them everywhere you want (as in the example).

If you already have a structure that already encapsulates both the `DataGrid` and the `SimplePager`, then attach that `Composite` to `UiBinder`, like any other widget.

In general, you do not have to extend `DataGrid` (or any other cell widget) to provide pagination. Simply *compose* the structure as you prefer.

Hope to have understood you question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I dont want just composition because, then my composed widget should provide all APIs of grid or users will have to do `getGrid()` from my composed widget and then used it. So I need to extend `DataGrid`. I don't know how to do the same in UI binder